# IIS unwanted redirect to port 8080

Tags: wordpress, redirect, iis

i have an own webserver on a virtual machine in the internet. This server worked very well so far.

Today i tried to deploy my new wordpress website. In order to keep old
website running and deploy the new, i set the bindings of new website to port 8080 instead of 80.

When i finished deployment, stopped the old site and set the bindings of new site back to 80 and started this new site on myserver.

Since this, i can't connect to my website froum outside or when browsing it within IIS anymore. The browser always appends 8080 at the end of address.

I restarted site, server, checked the bindings 10 times, no change.

It is IIS 8.5 running on Win 2012 R2 standard.

The error message in the browser is:

Firefox cannot establish connection to www.mysite.com:8080

I am not clear what is appending 8080. Could it be related to DNS somehow ?
Or a local config file. I made a search and found no entries for 8080.

Additional information: 
1. i have an SSL cert installed and linked to the page
2. I have redirect rule defined http->https
3. This all worked before switching to new website
4. When i do a blank wordpress installation, i can reach the site via https but not http -> 8080 appended in browser
5. When deploying the new webiste, i made a default install of wordpress, then
   migrating with a WP plugin, called "All-in-one WP migration"
6. After migration, another plugin (restored by migration) - YOAST SEO - posted that my website can't be indexed by search engine. I should check with google webmaster tools for mobile webiste compatibility. After 2 new installations, this check finally was successfull and also YOAST SEO did not list this error anymore.

However, when trying to visit my site from outside or from WP dashboard, the site
cannot be reached and in the browser always port 8080 gets appended.

Where can i look for the fault or what is appending this wrong port ?
Allow me to repeat: At the beginning, i mapped the new site to port 8080 in order
to check it during my old website running but, after fnished, iset the bindings of the new site back to 80 (and 443 with SSL).
Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

Damn it. It was a cookie problem. After deleting cookies in my chrome (on external machine) and firefox (on webserver), i can reach my new site via https and http which is redirected to https.